# Writing files to disk more than the size limitation

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, file-writing

the test is on `64-bit x86` Linux.

I have some `x86 32-bit` assembly code, which tries to write a large size of log data to the disk. It is something like this:

```
logging_flush:
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
andl    $-16, %esp
subl    $32, %esp
movl    $438, 8(%esp)       <--- 666
movl    $1089, 4(%esp)      <--- O_WRONLY|O_APPEND|O_CREAT
movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
call    open
movl    %eax, 28(%esp)
movl    $buf, %eax
movl    $0x1000000, 8(%esp)
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
movl    28(%esp), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    write
movl    28(%esp), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    close
leave
ret

section .rodata
.LC1:
.string "trace.bin"
```

However, due to the size limitation, the size of dumpped log file would not become larger than `2G`.

I tried to compile my code in this way:

```
gcc final.s -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m32 -lm
```

But then no byte can be written into the log file..

I also tried to use `fopen64`, but it just cannot work.. Am I missed anything here? Could anyone give me some help in adjusting the above assembly code?

Comment: You actually do not compile, but assemble. What is the reason you added the C tag?

Comment: You don't check the return value of `open(2)`.  Write this part in C.  The CPU time spent on system calls will dwarf the difference between your asm and compiler output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `O_LARGEFILE`. See [man open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open):

> O_LARGEFILE
>       (LFS) Allow files whose sizes cannot be represented in an off_t (but can be represented in an off64_t) to be opened.

So, the code could look like this:

```
# O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE
movl    $0x1|0x40|0x400|0x8000, 4(%esp)
```

Comment: I have to say, Jester, I'm really impressed with the breadth of assembly experience that you have!  :)